# Joi nested `when` conditions failed in schema definition with `ERR_ASSERTION ` error

Tags: node.js, joi

I have been trying to work with Joi (old version 14.3.1) to create a schema and unfortunately, I am stuck. I have tried multiple ways to define schemas but results always come with an error in the schema definition.

Here is my schema definition:

```
 const allowedUser = {
    admin: 'ADMIN',
    normal: 'NORMAL'
  };

  const schema = validator
    .object()
    .keys({
      user: validator.any().valid(Object.values(allowedUser)).required(),
      context: validator.object().default({})
    })
    .when('user', {
      is: allowedUser.admin,
      then: validator.when(validator.object({ context: validator.exist() }), {
        then: validator.object().keys({
          session: validator.string().required()
        })
      })
    })
    .when('user', {
      is: allowedUser.normal,
      then: validator.when(validator.object({ context: validator.exist() }), {
        then: validator.object().keys({
          id: validator.string().required()
        })
      })
    });
```

Another schema definition that i tried:

```
  const schema = validator.object().keys({
    user: validator.any().valid(Object.values(allowedUser)).required(),
    context: validator
      .object()
      .when('user', {
        is: allowedUser.admin,
        then: validator.when('context', {
          is: validator.exist(),
          then: validator.object().keys({
            session: validator.string().required()
          })
        })
      })
      .when('user', {
        is: allowedUser.normal,
        then: validator.when('context', {
          is: validator.exist(),
          then: validator.object().keys({
            id: validator.string().required()
          })
        })
      })
      .default({})
  });
```

So conditions for schema are as follows:

1. In the case of `user` type `ADMIN`: if  `context` property is defined it should contain property `session`. if `context` property is undefined it should set the default to `{}`
2. In the case of `user` type `NORMAL`: if  `context` property is defined it should contain property `id`. if `context` property is undefined it should set value default to `{}`
3. Implicit case is if `context` property contains unknown property it should fail too

When I run the code I always get an error in schema definition which is as follows:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot merge type object with another type: alternatives
```

My minimal example code is as follows:

```
const validator = require('joi');


  const allowedUser = {
    admin: 'ADMIN',
    normal: 'NORMAL'
  };

  const bodyWhenUndefined = {
    user: 'ADMIN',
    message: 'Hi'
  };

  const bodyWhenValidDefined = {
    user: 'ADMIN',
    message: 'Hi'
  };


  const bodyWhenDefinedEmpty = {
    user: 'ADMIN',
    message: 'Hi 2',
    context: {}
  };

  const bodyWhenDefinedWrong = {
    user: 'admin',
    message: 'Hi 3',
    context: {abc: 'wrong property'}
  };

  const schema = validator
    .object()
    .keys({
      user: validator.any().valid(Object.values(allowedUser)).required(),
      context: validator.object().default({})
    })
    .when('user', {
      is: allowedUser.admin,
      then: validator.when(validator.object({ context: validator.exist() }), {
        then: validator.object().keys({
          session: validator.string().required()
        })
      })
    })
    .when('user', {
      is: allowedUser.normal,
      then: validator.when(validator.object({ context: validator.exist() }), {
        then: validator.object().keys({
          id: validator.string().required()
        })
      })
    });


   const resultSuccess = validator.validate(bodyWhenValidDefined, schema);
    console.log("This is with success in validation",resultSuccess.value);

    const result = validator.validate(bodyWhenUndefined, schema);
    console.log("This is with default context property",result.value);


    const resultWithEmptyError = validator.validate(bodyWhenDefinedEmpty, schema);
    console.log("This should come with error with required property session",resultWithEmptyError.error);

    const resultWithWrongProp = validator.validate(bodyWhenDefinedWrong, schema);
    console.log("This should come with error with required property session",resultWithWrongProp.error);
```

I have created a working REPL fiddle [here](https://repl.it/join/qvvkcdli-fahimmahmoodmir) Help would be appreciated to tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to a REPL found [here](https://runkit.com/embed/bu8gr4gt8mhx). I got the idea of how a nested schema can be defined based on sibling property value. You can simply provide `then` condition with the object and define the required properties. here is the working schema:

```
  const schema = validator.object().keys({
    user: validator.any().valid(Object.values(allowedUser)).required(),
    message: validator.string(),
    context: validator
      .object()
      .when('user', {
        is: allowedUser.admin,
        then: {
          session: validator.required()
        }
      })
      .when('user', {
        is: allowedUser.normal,
        then: {
          id: validator.required()
        }
      })
      .default({})
  });
```